# Creating a 3D Carousel in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, 3d

I would like to make a 3D carousel of planes which have videos or images used as textures. I know this can be done in WPF but I'm interested to know if such a thing is possible in Sivlerlight and how much different and more(less) difficult would it be to create as opposed to the one in WPF.

Are there Viewport3Ds, MeshGeometries, ModelVisual3Ds and such things(or other equivalents) in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also the two videos by Jesse Liberty that he blogs about [here](http://jesseliberty.com/2009/02/19/carousel-video-posted-%E2%80%93-parts-1-and-2/).

**Edit**:

Ahh, now you added some other details to your question.  Frankly forget it.  If you want do serious 3D work like that then silverlight just isn't equiped for it.  There are no such 3D types in Silverlight.  There was the [kit3D](http://www.codeplex.com/Kit3D) project but that hasn't moved much in well over a year now.

The closest native Silverlight gets to 3D is the `Projection` class.   As some examples show with some home grown math you can provide some 3Dness to your UI but you have to do all the work.

Answer (score 2):

what you're probably looking for is a *Cover Flow* control. I'm using telerik controls for silverlight and they have one in their package: [RadCoverFlow for Silverlight](https://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/coverflow.aspx)

[image]
<sub>(source: [telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com/libraries/radcontrols_for_silverlight/coverflow_screenshot.sflb))</sub>

there is also one available on codeplex: [Silverlight Cover Flow](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=silverlightcoverflow)

[image]

this one I didn't try myself so can't tell you if it's any good

hope this helps, regards

Comment: It's not exactly what I had in mind. I want an circle in the air around which items rotate, this is just from one side to the other. And I want to create something like that and not use some else's.
My question is about how much different is 3D work in Silverlight from WPF(if there is any in Silverlight).